# more concise comparison of two lists?

Tags: python, list, compare

I would like to know if there is a general way in python to compare elements two lists (e.g. element from list 1 greater than element from list 2) in a more concise way than this:

```
    t1 = [1,1,0]
    t2 = [2,2,1]
    for I in range(len(t1)):
        if t1[I] > t2[I]:
            return False
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `any()` or `all()` to test (respectively) if a condition holds for any element or all of the elements in a list, coupled with `zip` to stick together the two lists. For example, the code in the question can be implemented more concisely like this:

```
not any(x > y for x, y in zip(t1, t2))
=> True
```

Or equivalently, as pointed by @squiguy in the comments:

```
all(x <= y for x, y in zip(t1, t2))
=> True
```

Comment: For me it's more natural to say `all(x < y for x, y in zip(t1, t2))`.

Comment: @squiguy good call, I edited my answer with your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I like that it's a general solution to comparisons.

Answer (score 2):

Lists (and sequences in general) are compared in lexicographical order (element by element), exactly as you want. So, your loop is equivalent to:

```
return not t1 > t2
```

Of course if the two lists are different lengths, there are various cases that will be handled differently (e.g., your code would return an `IndexError` in some cases where the other would return False). But really, you have to define what exactly you want to happen in those cases, and then actually coding tests for them will be easy—except that half the time, what you'll want is exactly what the default list comparison already does.